# Consider a line with a scalar equation, determine the vector equation of a perpendicular.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Consider the line with scalar equation $4x + 5y + 20 = 0$.

a) Determine a position vector perpendicular to this line.

b) What is the vector equation of the line?

I found two points of the line with that scalar equation which are $(0, -4)$, and $(-5, 0)$. I found the slope to be $-4/5$, and then took the negative reciprocal which is 5/4 so thus the slope is this. Since a position vector is in the form , I can write 5/4 as <4, 5> and thus this is my position vector I'm guessing. However, no idea how to find the vector equation of the line...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The equation
$$
4x + 5y + 20 = 0 \iff \\
b = -\frac{20}{\sqrt{4^2 + 5^2}}
=(x, y) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{4^2 + 5^2}} (4, 5) 
= u \cdot n \iff \quad (*) \\
b = u \cdot n
$$
is the equation of an affine hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is a line, with unit normal vector $n$ and distance $\lvert b \rvert$ from the origin.
The last statement can be seen from inserting $u = -d \, n$, the shortest vector from the origin to end on the line, with a length of $d=- b > 0$ (times the unit normal vector $n$).

[image: the line, a normal and the shortest distance vector]

The above $n$ should serve as an answer to a).

For b) you could use $(*)$ which is a vector equation for $u=(x,y)$ in normal form or use $u_0 + t \, u_1$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_0 = -d \,n$ and $u_1$ some vector orthogonal to $n$, e.g. $u_1=(5,-4)$.